# How to associate two entities based on a property comparison in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I would like to create an optional ManyToOne association between two entities based on whether `entity1.name equals entity2.nameOf1`, but I don't want to have to maintain this relationship in my service layer by adding, removing, fetching objets, I just want that when I get an entity2, either hibernate adds a `left join entity1 e1 on e1.name = e2.nameOf1` to the select query or that it waits for a call entity2.getEntity1() to query for entity1 with a `where e1.name == ?` with nameOf1 as argument. I have tried so far by using @JoinFormula annotation but there is very little documentation about it. I'm using hibernate version 3.5.6 with annotations.

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   @Column(unique = true)
   private String name;

   ...getter&setters...
}
@Entity
public class Entity2 {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   private String someProp;
   private String nameOf1;

   @ManyToOne(optional = true)
   // How to join them? this doesn't work
   // @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({ @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = 
   //      @JoinFormula(value = "nameOf1", referencedColumnName = "name")) })
   // neither does
   // @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({ @JoinColumnOrFormula(column =
   //      @JoinColumn(name = "nameOf1", referencedColumnName = "name", 
   //          insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)) })
   //@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   private Entity1 entity1;

   ...getter and setters...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just use a query to do that:

```
select e1 from Entity1 e1 where e1.name = :name
```

If you really want to go this road, a simple ManyToOne with a JoinColumn should be sufficient. You need to make it non-insertable and non-updatable, though:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "nameOf1", referencedColumnName = "name", 
            insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Entity1 entity1;
```

Comment: I have tried what you propose, it creates a foreign key constraint on entity2 table that crashes any insert (as it is insertable=false it will be null)

Comment: A null would not break a foreign key constraint. And it's not insertable because the same column is already mapped by the nameOf1 persistent field. And you're not forced to let Hibernate create the schema for you (although having an FK is a good thing).

Comment: you are 100% right, but then how do I allow the case that nameOf1 has a value that does not match any entity1, and thus entity1 prop is null? other than dropping the FK manually (it would mess up my HSQL unit tests)

Comment: That's another good reason to not use a ManyToOne, but use a query: you might have a nameOf1 which doesn't exist in the entity1 table. Hibernate has the @NotFound annotation for this, though. And of course, you shouldn't have an FK constraint on the column. I hate letting Hibernate generate the schema for me for this kind of reasons. But I maintain that the best solution is to use a query.

Comment: you right about the query, but there are other reasons that I haven't explained on why I'm trying to do this...

Comment: @NotFound solved the FK issues (I didn't know about this annotation) and I figured out that in my unit test scenario I have to evict the object I create and then refetch it, previously I was just trying to fetching it but probably the query hit the session cache and getEntity1() was not reloaded and returned null. Thanks a lot!!